# WebView (Media Related) Functionalities Stopped Working in Android 7+

Tags: android, webview

I have a WebView App which uploads images from user's device and plays music from the webView itself. The is working fine for Marshmallow and lower versions of Android but not for Nougat and above. 
Also images in the modal are not being displayed.

Here's the code from `MainActivity.java`:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        return imageFile;
    }

    public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

        // For Android 5.0
        public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
            // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
            if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
                mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
            }
            mFilePathCallback = filePath;

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                // Create the File where the photo should go
                File photoFile = null;
                try {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    // Error occurred while creating the File
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
                }

                // Continue only if the File was successfully created
                if (photoFile != null) {
                    mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                            Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                } else {
                    takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }

            Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

            Intent[] intentArray;
            if (takePictureIntent != null) {
                intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
            } else {
                intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

            Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

            return true;

        }

        // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

            mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

            File imageStorageDir = new File(
                    Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                    , "AndroidExampleFolder");

            if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
                // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
                imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
            }

            // Create camera captured image file path and name
            File file = new File(
                    imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                            + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            + ".jpg");

            mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

            // Camera capture image intent
            final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            i.setType("image/*");

            // Create file chooser intent
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

            // Set camera intent to file chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                    , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

            // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
            startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


        }

        // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
        }

        //openFileChooser for other Android versions
        public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                    String acceptType,
                                    String capture) {

            openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            if (requestCode != INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE || mFilePathCallback == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            Uri[] results = null;

            // Check that the response is a good one
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (data == null) {
                    // If there is not data, then we may have taken a photo
                    if (mCameraPhotoPath != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCameraPhotoPath)};
                    }
                } else {
                    String dataString = data.getDataString();
                    if (dataString != null) {
                        results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }

            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(results);
            mFilePathCallback = null;

        } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            if (requestCode != FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE || mUploadMessage == null) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                return;
            }

            if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {

                if (null == this.mUploadMessage) {
                    return;
                }

                Uri result = null;

                try {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {

                        result = null;

                    } else {

                        // retrieve from the private variable if the intent is null
                        result = data == null ? mCapturedImageURI : data.getData();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "activity :" + e,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
                mUploadMessage = null;

            }
        }

        return;
    }
    private void startKioskService() { // ... and this method
        startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, CheckTopActivityService.class));
    }
```

What's the issue here? Is there new functions for uploading images in Nougat? Also why the music is not playing? Should I ask permission to play music?

Comment: Which type of error are you getting share your logcat? Is is coming when you click image from camera?

Comment: There are no errors. When I click on the image from the gallery it gets uploaded but when I take a picture with the camera it don't take the image in the file input box.

Comment: Should you use file provider in nougat.

Comment: @Champandorid Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

If your targetSdkVersion is Nougat, we have to use FileProvider class to give access to the particular file or folder to make them accessible for other apps. We create our own class inheriting FileProvider in order to make sure our FileProvider doesn't conflict with FileProviders declared in imported dependencies as described [Here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-share-access-to-file-with-fileprovider-on-android-nougat/en)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: targetSdkVersion is Marshmallow

Comment: @EvilTech What do you mean  by marshmallow if you want to run your code on nougat you have to use file provider to access another app